# Collapse on Grid breaks Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I am learning to create a website using Material-ui and React.

I want to create a collapsable grid where some rows are collapsed/expanded based on the state of page.

When I add a collapse component in the Grid layout, the Grid layout is broken.

I created a sample code here ( https://codesandbox.io/embed/jolly-golick-3lwt5) for demonstration.

Here, you see the collapsed part (where current condition is 'expanded' is not showing as expected.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Collapse adds [three layers of divs](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.2.1/packages/material-ui/src/Collapse/Collapse.js#L182) around its children ([container, wrapper, and wrapperInner](https://material-ui.com/api/collapse/#css)). These additional layers between the container `Grid` and item `Grid` are going to prevent the flexbox layout of the `Grid` from working correctly. It is probably possible to get the look you are aiming for while still using `Collapse`, but it probably is **not** straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler but only shows the collapse-in animation.

```
<Grid item xs={3} style={{ display: showCollapse ? "block" : "none" }}>
   <Collapse in={showCollapse}>
     <Button>Button</Button>
  </Collapse>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

This right here worked for me:

```
import MuiCollapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'

const GridItemXs12 = (props) => <Grid item xs={12} {...props} />

const Collapse = (props) => {
  const classes = useCollapseStyles()
  return (
    <MuiCollapse
      component={GridItemXs12}
      classes={{
        hidden: classes.hidden,
      }}
      {...props}
    >
        {/* This spacing has to match with the one in the container
            outside the collapse */}
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {props.children}
        </Grid>
    </MuiCollapse>
  )
}

const useCollapseStyles = makeStyles({
  hidden: {
    // The grid item's padding normally balances with the negative padding
    // of the container outside the Collapse.
    // But when the collapse hides its content, the padding of the item
    // is still taking up space, creating an unwanted space.
    // The 'hidden' style rule is only applied when the collapse finishes
    // hiding its content
    padding: '0 !important',
  },
})
```

Then use this custom `Collapse` as a direct descendant of a `Grid container`

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Collapse in={/* your controlled variable */}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          The content inside this grid item looks as if the item were
          directly inside the container
        </Grid>
      </Collapse>
    </Grid>
  )
}
```

Here is a modified version of your sample code using this approach https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-hodgkin-rk2wv, I added an onClick handler to the main div so that clicking anywhere within it toggles the collapse.

This solution assumes that you want to collapse something taking up the full width of your container. It also assumes that you want some spacing in that container (actually, without the spacing the grid doesn't break at all). Also, there is some jank in the animation when the padding style gets applied, the more the spacing, the more noticeable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope is not too late

Only add

```
style={{width: "100%"}}
```

or use

```js
<Collapse sx={{
        [`&.${collapseClasses.root}`]: {
          width: "100%",
        },
}}>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).